# Highligligh particular areas based on X-axis data

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

SO What I am trying to do is that I am trying to fetch data from CSV File, and from other CSV file I am trying to Highlight a particular area from the Chart.

**For Eg.:**
 This is the Chart I am getting . 
By adding the Following Code.

```
$.get('abc.csv', function(data) {
var lines = []
lines = data.split('\n');
console.log(lines);


var ecgData=[];
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
    if(lineNo >= 0)
        {

        ecgData[lineNo-0] = parseFloat(lineContent.substring(lineContent.lastIndexOf(",")+1) );
          //gibber=500;

        //m=m+500;
        }//console.log('PPG Data', ppgData[ppgNo-0])

    });


 featurex = [5,10,14,34,56,78,90,95] ;
 featurey = [0,0,1,0,0,3,0,2];
  zip = (xs, ys) => xs.reduce((acc, x, i) => (acc.push([x, ys[i]]), acc), []);

    //console.log(ecg);
    console.log(ecgData);

    Highcharts.chart('ecg', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
             zoomType: 'xy',
                panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift'
        },
        credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
        title: {
        text: 'ECG Data'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {

        crosshair: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'ECG Peaks'
        }
    },
   tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: '',
        lineWidth: 1,
        data: ecgData,
         animation: {
                duration: 14000
            }

    },
    {    type: 'column',
        name: 'Features',
        data: zip(featurex, featurey),
        animation: {
                duration: 14000
      }
  }
     ]
});

});
```

**My Chart :**
[image]

Now as you can see from the Chart. I am getting the `features` data as bars in the chart.

```
 featurex = [5,10,14,34,56,78,90,95] ;
 featurey = [0,0,1,0,0,3,0,2];
```

but that is not what I want what I want is that  where the features x value is 1, I want to highlight that area with a particular color, where it is 2, it should be filled with other color Like an example below: 
[image]

**Note:** its just an example how the data should look don't math the data with the above image data.

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `load` event you can check if a point meets your condition and add `plotBands` to your chart.

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
                points = this.series[0].points,
                from,
                to,
                plotBands = [];

            points.forEach(function(point, i) {
                from = points[i - 1] ? points[i - 1].x : point.x;
                to = points[i + 1] ? points[i + 1].x : point.x;

                if (point.y === 1) {
                    plotBands.push({
                        color: 'blue',
                        from: from,
                        to: to
                    });
                } else if (point.y === 2) {
                    plotBands.push({
                        color: 'green',
                        from: from,
                        to: to
                    });
                }
            });

            xAxis.update({
                plotBands: plotBands
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vm0ouwp5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands